# Getting fakeclip plugin to work with Vim and tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, vim-plugin

I have downloaded fakeclip.vim and put it to ~/.vim/plugin/

Now I create a new tmux session and open Vim in two panes. When I use `" & y` I get:
E117: Unknown function: fakeclip#yank

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by loading plugins using [vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen.git):

1. Installed Pathogen to ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
2. Installed fakeclip to ~/.vim/bundle/
3. Added this to .vimrc

> ```
> execute pathogen#infect()
> syntax on
> filetype plugin indent on
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is not installed correctly: you must put each file and subdirectory in its corresponding directory under `~/.vim/`.

```
autoload/fakeclip.vim    --->    ~/.vim/autoload/fakeclip.vim
doc/fakeclip.txt         --->    ~/.vim/doc/fakeclip.txt
plugin/fakeclip.vim      --->    ~/.vim/plugin/fakeclip.vim
t/whatever.vim           --->    ~/.vim/t/whatever.vim
```

But I think you are barking the wrong tree: install a proper vim if you want clipboard support.